# Thread pool in r2dbc-postgresql

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc-postgresql

Can you help me understand? There is a Spring Boot (3.0.2) service with Spring Data R2DBC repository and r2dbc-postgresql driver. By default, a pool of 10 connections and 10 reactor-tcp-nio threads is created. I have enabled logging of R2DBC queries in the database and logging in the operators after the reactive repository. 1000 HTTP requests per second have been generated using JMeter. The result is that I see that all queries in the database and all operators after the reactive repository are executed in the reactor-tcp-nio-1 thread. If a breakpoint is set in the doOnNext operator (not on the line, but on the lambda) in the IDE, the reactor-tcp-nio-1 thread will suspend, and all other threads will still not be utilized.

```
package com.example;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class R2DBCApplication {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(R2DBCApplication.class);

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(R2DBCApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

```java
package com.example;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import java.util.UUID;

@RestController
public class ValueController {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ValueController.class);

    @Autowired
    private ValueRepository repository;

    @GetMapping("/value")
    public Mono<String> get() {
        final var uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        log.info("start for uuid = {}", uuid);
        return repository
                .findById(1L)
                .map(ValueEntity::getId)
                .map(String::valueOf)
                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.fromSupplier(() -> uuid))
                .doOnNext(v -> log.info("after switchIfEmpty uuid = {}", v));
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Column;
import org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Table;

@Table("value")
public class ValueEntity {

    @Id
    @Column("id")
    private Long id;

    @Column("value")
    private String value;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(final Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(final String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example;

import org.springframework.data.r2dbc.repository.R2dbcRepository;

public interface ValueRepository extends R2dbcRepository<ValueEntity, Long> {

}
```

```
server.port: 9080
spring:
  application.name: r2dbc-service
  r2dbc:
    url: r2dbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/postgres
    username: postgres
    password: 12345
    properties:
      schema: public

logging.level.root: DEBUG
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>r2dbc-postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Is this the expected behavior? I assumed that all 10 reactor-tcp-nio threads would be utilized.
What can be done to make queries and operator execution happen in different threads? (reactor-tcp-nio-1, ..., reactor-tcp-nio-10).

Do you really need to add publishOn or subscribeOn after every call to a reactive repository?

Comment: 1000 requests but with what rate?

Comment: I think it's close to ~1000 rps, but processing these requests (in the code from the question) is done in a single thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is likely already fixed. See https://github.com/r2dbc/r2dbc-pool/issues/190

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).